# Error occurs when I try to mount an array inside the for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

Error occurs when I try to mount an array inside the for loop in python

I am in a transition of language, so small doubts arise in the day to day.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
data = []
for index, linha in enumerate(reg2):
    data['lista'][index]['name'] = linha.name,
    data['lista'][index]['document'] = linha.document

    data.append(data)
```

Comment: You are using `['name']` and `['document']` to access a list index.  These values need to be integers or slices, not strings.  Also, remove four spaces from the start of each line after `data = []`

Comment: How could it be? thank you

Comment: It also looks like you want `data` to be a dictionary, not a list. What do you envisage the final `data` object would look like if you did `print(data)`?

Comment: In this format: { 'lista' : [
    { 'name' : 'jhon', 'document' : 'pdf'}, 
    { 'name' : 'maria', 'document' : 'doc'}
]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dictionary of lists of dictionaries, not a list. Do not enumerate anything; in fact, you do not even need a loop:

```
docs = [{'name': linha.name, 'document': linha.document} for linha in reg2]
data = {'lista' : docs}
```